# Automatic pruning of old ZFS snapshots

Tags: 22.04, zfs, snapshot

So I selected ZFS when installing Ubuntu 22.04 because I wanted to try it out. I love the snapshot feature, however I found that due to daily `apt-upgrade` it accumulates a lot of snapshots consuming a lot of space. (and starting to complain about low space on rpool/bpool)

How and where can I set some sensible automatic removal rules?

E.g. I want to automatically only keep

- manually named snapshots
- the last 3 `apt-upgrade` snapshots
- 1 or 2 weekly/monthly backup snapshots.

It seems that especially when packages with large binaries such as CUDA get updated a lot of space is used for the snapshots...

Comment: While I unfortunately don't have the available time/energy to write this up as an answer in this moment, you and/or others facing this may find https://didrocks.fr/2020/06/04/zfs-focus-on-ubuntu-20.04-lts-zsys-state-collection/ to be helpful... tuning up a new `zsys.conf` can help.

Answer (score 2):

Canonical does not offer a utility to do this, because it's a lot of work to do this robustly and well in a way that covers all edge cases. And you don't want to make a mistake when deleting other people's data at scale. I think canonical underestimated the scope of their zsys project and their confidence in autopruning root datasets across a hundred thousand installs.

All that said, I've written a script that's good enough for *me*. Whether it suits your purposes is another question entirely, and one I cannot answer. Adjust the value of `keep` to the number of snapshots you want to keep. You can put this script in `/etc/cron.daily` as zfs-prune.sh (or whatever you like) and mark it executable.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

keep=10
num_snaps=$(zfs list -t snapshot -o name -S creation | grep -Po '@autozsys_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$' | uniq | wc -l)
printf "Found %d autosys versions. Configured to keep %d.\n" $num_snaps $keep
if [[ $num_snaps -le $keep ]]; then
    printf "no need to prune.\n"
    exit 0
fi

num_to_prune=$(( num_snaps - keep ))
printf "Pruning %d zsys versions.\n" $num_to_prune
if [[ $num_to_prune -le 0 ]]; then
    printf "Error - no snapshots to prune.\n"
    exit 127
fi

if [[ $num_to_prune -ge $num_snaps ]]; then
    printf "Error - won't remove all snapshots.\n"
    exit 127
fi


for zsys_snap in $(zfs list -t snapshot -o name -S creation | grep -Po '@autozsys_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$' | uniq | tail -n $num_to_prune); do
    printf "Removing $zsys_snap\n"
    zfs list -t snapshot -o name | grep "${zsys_snap}$" | xargs -n 1 zfs destroy -vr
done
```

### Limitations

This script has a few limitations that you should be aware of and accept (or address) before using it.

- It doesn't distinguish between USERDATA and ROOT datasets, so if you have a lot of newer zsys snapshots of one or the other it may leave you with no snapshots of the other.
- This does nothing with grub boot options (I'm not sure if zsys does or not).
- I only have a few checks to avoid obvious calculation/overflow errors.
- This script assumes that all snapshots with the same name are created on the same date and relies on `zfs list` sorting by creation date to determine which snapshots are old.

If you're good with those constraints and are willing to bet your data on it, then have at it. But this is provided without warranty or guarantee. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you, this was useful.  That said, I was hoping for something closer to official/supported, and found this: https://didrocks.fr/2020/06/04/zfs-focus-on-ubuntu-20.04-lts-zsys-state-collection/ -- probably deserves to be sumarized and written up as an answer here.  I'd do so if I had more time at the moment... leaving it as a comment here in hopes it will at least be found by others landing here.

Answer (score 1):

I use the utility [`zfs-auto-snapshot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/zfs-auto-snapshot.8.html) for automating this.

This can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install zfs-auto-snapshot
```

This program puts the following file on your system for scheduling: `/etc/cron.d/zfs-auto-snapshot`, where I have the following contents:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# */5 * * * * root zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=frequent --keep=12 //
# 00 * * * * root zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=hourly --keep=24 //
45 23 * * * root zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=daily --keep=30 //
# 59 23 * * 0 root zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=weekly --keep=4 //
# 00 00 1 * * root zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=monthly --keep=12 //
```

As you can see, this lets you define different snapshot labels that run at different intervals, and also how many to keep.

You could add the following line to remove additional snapshots with the label `apt-upgrade`:

```
59 23 * * * root zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=apt-upgrade --destroy-only --keep=3 //
```

Please not the the `//` at the end of each line means *all ZFS datasets*. You could also give a filesystem or volume name here, to apply the operation only to this dataset.

Also note that `zfs-auto-snapshot` also puts files in all the directories `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly` and `/etc/cron.monthly`. I've disabled those by removing the executable attribute.

Comment: I don't think this prunes the autozsys snapshots made by zsys during apt operations. It doesn't on my 22.04 install. This only seems to prune snapshots made by this tool.

Comment: Ok. Maybe this is because of the label. I'm not sure, since I don't use ZFS on root. If it's not working, maybe you need to create your own script to remove additional snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/788517) to a question on a sister site, I discovered [**`zfs-prune-snapshots`**](https://github.com/bahamas10/zfs-prune-snapshots), a bash script [by Dave Eddy](https://github.com/bahamas10/zfs-prune-snapshots). See its [usage](https://github.com/bahamas10/zfs-prune-snapshots#usage) section for details.

To download the latest version of the script and make it executable:

```sh
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/zfs-prune-snapshots/master/zfs-prune-snapshots

chmod +x ./zfs-prune-snapshots
```

To run the script in dry mode, i.e. without actually pruning, use the `-n` flag. To see the output of removing snapshots older than a week across all zpools, run:

```sh
./zfs-prune-snapshots -n -v 1w
```

If you feel comfortable deleting all the listed snapshots, run:

```sh
sudo ./zfs-prune-snapshots -R -v 1w
```

The script uses [`zfs destroy`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/zfs-destroy.8.html) under the hood which requires superuser rights. The `-R` flag instructs it to recursively destroy all dependents (children and cloned file systems outside the target hierarchy). Without the `-R` flag, no snapshots could be deleted in my case.

In my case, running the above resulted in the deletion of over 3000 snapshots that had accumulated over about 10 months of continuous usage of Ubuntu 22.04. By deleting these snapshots, the boot time was reduced by several minutes and is now as fast again as it was after the initial installation of Ubuntu.

You could run the above via a Cronjob to automate snapshot pruning. But beware that the `zfs destroy` manpage states:

> Extreme care should be taken when applying either the **-r** or the **-R** options, as they can destroy large portions of a pool and cause unexpected behavior for mounted file systems in use.